# Reacting to discord notifications from another app

Tags: notifications, windows-10, wireshark, discord

I would like to know if there's any way to read notifications from discord app to be able to fire actions on my computer. I have been looking for information about action center in windows 10 but it seems there is no public api to access all notifications in the action center just the ones from your app.

On the other hand I have been using WireShark to check the network traffic but it is encripted so, there's no way (that I know) to check the decripted notification message.

I can't use a discord bot to do this. It must be done in my desktop machine.
Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Discord has an API, have you looked into interfacing with it from a Windows application you are writing ? This is quite vague of a question.. https://github.com/RogueException/Discord.Net Someone has done in dotNet

Comment: @Pogrindis I didn't know that, thanks for the tip. I have added a bit more of information. I can't use discord API because I must do this without any bot in the channel. And yes, I had a look at Dircord.Net but I can't used because I can't add a bot the the channel.

Comment: I don't know the specific details as I have not done it before, but their documentation seems to be on point, I suspect you will require their websocket // webhook, but that's just as assumption : https://discord.foxbot.me/docs/api/Discord.WebSocket.html

Comment: Anyway your wireshark message about disectors put me on track. Here is how one can decript on the client (forget about MIM attacks, I'm not looking for this kind of things) the data comming from SSL protocol https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hh9SRJpK5hI. Thanks @Pogrindis

Comment: Hah I deleted that message because that route seems to be more of a hack rather than if their API allowed you to listen natively ! But good luck!